# Identifying the right motherboard for a project

Tags: pcb

Let's say you're trying to find a motherboard that has exactly this many of type x interface, and that many of type y interface, and you don't want any more interfaces that are usually on a motherboard but you know you won't use them.

- Is there a source that an engineer can use to find a specific motherboard for a project?
- If I can't find this specific motherboard, is there any framework that would allow me to customize a standard motherboard design easily. I don't think it's an easy undertaking to design one from scratch, but perhaps it's possible to start with a generic motherboard and use pcb to customize it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about a computer motherboard, I just use the Newegg power search. As for designing a single motherboard, thousands of man hours go into designing just one. And even some of the simplest still have many more than your typical 2 sided layout. There is also no "motherboard templates" that you can customize.

If you are talking about a interface board to link your many components together, you should start your design with the correct headers for your "daughter boards", and then add the processing power as needed. As for templates, I don't know of any off of the top of my head, but if you use header pins, you shouldn't need a template.